# Create contour plot from 3 vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a set of three vectors: x, y, and z that I want to turn into a contour plot.  Does anyone have an example of how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is well explained (and have examples)  http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html

Comment: My issue is that I do not have a grid, I only have 3 1xn matrices.  I need to adjust my vectors before I can make a contour

Comment: this contour(X,Y,Z) doesn't work? You can try filling your vectors with zeros too, I guess. Provide us some code